# Constrained Optimization Over Two Functions

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

I don't work in optimization; however, recently I have found myself needing to optimize a variety of functionals. I'm wondering if there is a way to efficiently approximate a solution to this minimization problem:

Suppose $I \subset \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $f \in L^1(\Omega)$ are given. Find $A,u$ which solve the following minimization problem:
\begin{equation*}
\min\limits_{A,u} \lambda \|f-u\|^2_{L^1(\Omega)}  + \int_{\Omega \backslash I} \int_{I} (u(y)-u(x))^2 A(x,y) dy dx
\end{equation*}
subject to the constrains $C_1 \leq \| A \|_{L^1(\Omega\times \Omega)} \leq C_2$ with $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $A(x,y) \geq 0$.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, you're right I need to clarify more. I'll edit the problem now.

Comment: Something is fishy about $A$. To start with, $\|A\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$ is a type error: $A:\Omega\times\Omega\to\mathbb R$, not $\Omega\to\mathbb R$. Second, if $u$ is unbounded, you can easily send the functional to $-\infty$ by $A$ approximating minus delta-measures at appropriate points. Maybe $A$ is actually fixed and $u$ is the only free parameter?